# Python request module gives error 400(bad request) for POST

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to http requests and trying to automate some work. But I am unable to get the required result. I have looked many posts and documentation of python requests module but there is no change in the result.

Code I wrote

```
def installFont():
    print "Installing font"
    urlToHit = "some http address"
    header_ = {  "UserID": "00000",  "PortalName": "EDC",  "ModifyBy" : "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX", "Content-Type" : "application/json"}

    body_ = {
  "Email": "abc@xyz.com",
  "AssetLicenseType": "Trial",
  "MachineIds":  ["machine1", "machine2"],
  "fontAsset":
  [
     {
          "FontId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "FontName": "Neue Aachen™ Pro Ultra Light",
          "FontUrl": "http://helveticaurl",
          "FontDownloadUrlAPI": "url",
          "FontDownloadUrl" : "url1,
          "FontFamilyName": "Neue Aachen™ Pro",
          "FontFamilyUrl": "http://FontFamilyUrl",
          "FontStyle": "Normal",
          "FontWeight": "100",
          "ExpiryDate": "2017-2-27 11:17:01",
          "FontFamilyId": "34"
     }                  
  ]
}

r = requests.request("POST", urlToHit, data=body_, headers=header_)
print r.headers
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

Itried same thing with postman which gives me correct result but via python I am getting output as

```
{'X-Processing-Time-Milliseconds': '3', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Server': 'Kestrel', 'Date': 'Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:51:59 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
400
{"Message":"''"}
```

I think I am doing some mistake while passing body_ in

`r = requests.request("POST", urlToHit, data=body_, headers=header_)`

Output via postman
`{"Message":"Created Successfully","SuccessCount":2,"FailCount":0}`

Comment: I further looked into it and I am assuming issue is with **fontAssest** field. When I remove this field from "body_", response is _{"Message":"'Atleast one font asset is required'"}_. But body_ works completely fine with POSTMAN tool. So **fontAsset** is list of dictionary. Maybe I need to shift focus on how I need to pass such request for post.

Comment: Please do not spare your time on this question. There is a special character **™** which needs to be taken care of. I am able to get required result now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
r = requests.post(urlToHit, json=body_, headers=headers_)
```

Please go through the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/).

Comment: I had already checked `r = requests.post(urlToHit, data=body_, headers=headers_)`. 'requests.post(urlToHit, data=body_, headers=headers_)' calls 'requests.request("POST", urlToHit, data=body_, headers=header_)'.

Comment: Also I have checked converting body_ into string `"""value of body_"""`. As its written in defination of  data = **:param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.**

Comment: Also I have tried r = requests.post(urlToHit, json=body_, headers=headers_) seeing the documentation but there is no change in the result.

Comment: it is an old post but have you tried `data = json.dumps(body)` in the requests?